# windbg: Debug prints are not thrown in Windows server 2012 and 2012 R2

Tags: visual-studio-2013, driver, windbg

After adding `D_DEBUG` and `DDEBUG_BUILD` flags in `C_DEFINES`, debug prints are not thrown in windbg

```
C_DEFINES= $(C_DEFINES) -D_DEBUG -DDEBUG_BUILD
```

For windows 7, debug prints are working.

I'm using VS2013 and WDK8.1 to compile the driver

Comment: Does this flag DDKBUILDENV works in VS2013?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082764/filesystem-minifilter-driver-compiled-with-wdk-8-0-not-showing-dbgprint-output

Comment: In my case, windbg prints appear in Windows 7. the same code is not printing debug information with Windows 2012 or Windows 8 onwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ed Kd_DEFAULT_Mask 8

Thanks to Rohan