# How to enable Kernel Traces in WinDBg

Tags: windows, kernel, windbg

I have already referred to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734335/kernel-trace-windows-7-windbg):

But didn't help. 
Issuing

```
ed Kd_DEFAULT_Mask 8
```

didn't cause any change. and I don't know how to add a DWORD here
 `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter` called DEFAULT with a value of 8, Because I can't see `Debug Print Filter` under my registry?

I have a way to verify whether the debug driver for my hardware is installed or not, But even after verifying that, I can't seem to get Kernel traces in windbg.
There is a tool called 
DbgView.exe in that I have enabled following Capture options:

```
Capture Win32
Capture Global Win32
Capture Kernel
Enable Verbose Kernel Output
Pass-through
Capture events
```

I was hoping this would enable kernel traces but without help.

Could someone tell me the standard way to doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to add Debug print key registry

:>reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter"

Error:  The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value

:>reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter" /V DEFAULT /t REG_DWORD /d 0xf

The operation completed successfully

:>reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter"

! REG.EXE VERSION 3.0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter
DEFAULT     REG_DWORD       0xf

Comment: I didn't even know you could do "reg add" from the cmd line, very handy!

Comment: It's "Debug Print Filter", not "Debug Print"

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the default mask to 0xF? Are you sure that your driver is actually generating trace messages after you have changed the **kd_default_mask** variable?

In terms of the registry based approach, you just create the Debug Print Filter key if it isn't already there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create this key. This key does not exist by default
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter`
The set the Default Value to 0xf. That will enable all messages.

More information can be found in ["Setting the Component Filter Mask"](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/reading-and-filtering-debugging-messages#identifying-the-component-name).

There is also a description how to set this for a single debugger session