# DbgView on Vmware Workstation 12 not capturing output

Tags: debugging, kernel, driver, windbg

I have a windows 10 x64 Os installed on my VMware Workstation 12. I would like to do driver related development on the VM, so I have Debug mode enabled and Driver Signing disabled. I can load my device driver successfully but none of my calls to DbgPrint are being displayed. I tried to use DbgView with "Capture Kernel" and "Capture global" checked, still nothing gets printed. I did run DbgView as Administrator. I even tried printing in Windbg X64, no luck. Has anyone dealt with this issue?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `DbgPrint`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kernel trace Windows 7 WinDbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734335/kernel-trace-windows-7-windbg)

Comment: bcdedit /debug on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default DbgPrint() outputs are disabled from Vista/Server2008 onwards. You may have to do below settings in registry to enable the debug prints.

1. Open up the registry.
2. Go to path, “**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter**”. If "Debug Print Filter" is not present then create it.
3. Add value “**DEFAULT**” : **REG_DWORD** : **0xFFFFFFFF** and then reboot.

After rebooting you will be able to get debug prints.