# WinDBG does not show the DbgPrint messages

Tags: c

I got a problem with WinDBG. It won't show the DbgPrint messages. And it is weird because it outputs the new lines, but not the message.

[image: Screenshot from WinDBG]]

Driver, in this case, is very simple:

```
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <wdf.h>

VOID Unload(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
    DbgPrint("Driver Unloaded \r \n");
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = Unload;
    DbgPrint("Hello Driver \r \n");

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am using the OSR Driver Loader, and it seems to be loading the driver successfully on to the system:

[image]

But, no output. Strange

Comment: You might have to enable the debug output in the registry. I had a similar issue a while back. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622094/dbgview-on-vmware-workstation-12-not-capturing-output

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have already changed that registry value directly from debugger with command: ed nt!Kd_Default_Mask 8 But still no luck

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this problem already. Solution for that was, after windbg attachment, I need to restart my VM, without turning off debugger and then everything works.